# Query rows from one table that does/does not have a relationship to another table

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, join

i have 3 tables
1. devices (id, deviceno, devicename)
2. programs (id, programname)
3. programdevices (id, programid, deviceid)

Now i need both 
1. All devices which have a relationship to a given programid
2. All devices which do not have a relationship to a given programid

i tried the following

```
SELECT d.id, d.deviceno, d.devicename FROM devices d
LEFT JOIN programdevices pd ON pd.program = 3 and pd.device = d.id
WHERE pd.device is null / is not null
```

but i always get an empty result.
thank to everyone for point me in the right direction

Comment: I fyou want all devices, why not just `SELECT d.id, d.deviceno, d.devicename FROM devices d` ? Do you have any additional thing you want from that query? And is the `/` really in your where clause?

Comment: not just all. first i want to display all devices that have an relationship to a given program. then when the user clicks "Add unused device" i want to display all devices that have not currently a relationship to the current program. the / is not really in the where clause. it stands for first or second case

Comment: In that case would that not be better done as two seperate queries?

Comment: sure i do that in separate select querys. but why does both select queries deliver an empty result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
SELECT d.id, d.deviceno, d.devicename, case when pd.programid IS null then 'NO' else 'YES' End as Relation  FROM devices d LEFT JOIN programdevices pd ON pd.device = d.id
```

By using This You will get all devices with column `Relation` . IF the Relation Field is `YES` then You have a relation else if `NO` you dont have a relation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I think It may help you...

```
    SELECT d.deviceno, d.devicename, p.programname
    FROM devices d
    JOIN programdevices pd ON pd.deviceid = d.id
    JOIN programs p ON p.id = pd.programid
    WHERE p.id !=3
    LIMIT 0 , 30
```